# Android resource linking failed with API 27 and API 26 or we can say below API 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If I am using 28 API then I am getting **Error: Program type already present: androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable** which force me to migrate to androidx. and migrating **androidx** which causing **error in my all the support fragments**

Android resource linking failed

```
Output:  E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:656: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:656: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Kunjan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\612f5de46ad621100ae4392104a3337f\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        E:\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\community_app\application\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.krs.vastipatrak\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by first Invalidate caches/Restart from **Android studio->File->Invalidate caches/Restart->Invalidate and Restart** and then going to the build/intermediates directory of the app and delete all the files and folders there and rebuild the project. In your case you can simply delete all the contents in this directory:
**E:\community_app\application\app\build\intermediates**

I hope this helps!